# The person living next door's

Tags: possessives

> Whose car got stolen?
>
> **The person living next door's** car got stolen.
>   I don't know what his name is.

Is using the apostrophe the way I've used in the above example grammatically correct?
Could you give me 2-3 more examples where the apostrophe is used the same way as I used it?

Comment: The question is wrong. It should be _Whose car got stolen?_ -- no apostrophes, different word. The second sentence is correct, though awkward. The _-'s_ possessives go at the end of a noun phrase, not at the end of a noun. So we say _the King of Bavaria's mistress_ and _a Doctor of Philosophy's robe_ even though the mistress doesn't belong to Bavaria, and the robe doesn't belong to Philosophy.

Comment: Thanks.
And thanks for pointing out that mistake in the first sentence as well. @JohnLawler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the way you use it in the sentence about the stolen car is correct.  In general, **'s** to indicate possession can go after a name, a noun, or a noun phrase.

- Andrew's car
- the king of Denmark's car
- King Frederick of Denmark's car
- King Frederick of Denmark's car's radiator
- the man who rode into town yesterday's horse

The longer and more complicated the noun phrase gets, the less good it sounds to just stick **'s** at the end of it, but it's always grammatically correct.

Reference: [possession](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine)